# Connecting to Postgres database with read only access.

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to restrict my connection to a database through the psql client to be read only. I.E. The role using to connect to the database has full privileges on it, but I want to restrict some of my connections to being read-only.

Is this possible or do I have to simply create a new database role with my desired privileges.

Comment: you can `ALTER USER username set default_transaction_read_only = on;` for this, but definetely creating a new user is better (because user can "swith off" ro transaction)

Answer (score 9):

Why not just

`SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY;`

This command can be issued after the connection is made, i.e. typed into 'psql' after it has started and connected to the database. It will affect all transactions started within the current psql session. There is a variant on the command which affects only the current transaction (see docs below).

This does provide a safeguard against operators accidentally modifying important data, but is not securely read-only - an attacker with access to this connection can simply set the characteristics back to "READ WRITE" again.

[Postgresql documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set-transaction.html).

Comment: Note: this only works until the user says `\c <db_name>`...

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Vao's comment, just use:

`SET default_transaction_read_only = on`

This is config to be applied to the connection setup. i.e. can be placed in your psqlrc or ~/.psqlrc file to affect all future invocations of psql.

This does provide a safeguard against operators accidentally modifying important data, but is not securely read-only - an attacker with access to a connection created this way could simply set the characteristics back to "READ WRITE" again.

[Postgresql documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#id-1.6.7.14.2.2.10.1.3)

Answer (score 2):

So if you are trying to connect to the database using the node pg module, then I would recommend to use the options Like below,
your client const should look like:

```
  new Client({  host: "localhost",
  user: "user name",
  port: 5432,
  database: "db name",
  options: "-c default_transaction_read_only=on"
})
```

You can also run this query after connecting:

```
    client.query(
  `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY;`,
  (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(res.rows);
    } else {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  }
);
```

But I find the first way better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create read-only user as -> create a new database user; grant connect on DB;
then grant usage on schema and then grant select on tables.

Here is a reference, https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-create-read-only-user.html

However allowing read-only to a fully privileged user over a (specific) connection isn't feasible (using built-in features).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think the closing statement is too broad. I presume your intention is to say that one cannot create a *securely* read-only connection. But if the aim is just to prevent operators accidental typos, then one *can* provide a read-only connection. The only caveat is that a user could easily switch it back to a read-write connection.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the client you are using to connect you can set the connection to read only mode.

Using DBeaver as an example https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4112

Comment: This answer would be much better if it didn't rely on a third-party tool like DBeaver which not many people use, and if it replicated the important details here, rather than just linking to some other page. But don't do that now - the details are already stated in other answers higher up the page.